# Hot-encoding warning when using gridsearch

Tags: scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding, grid-search

I ran an experiment with the classical holdout method to predict price and hot-encoded categorical data. However, when optimising, I got the warning below even though that I ignored the unknown columns. Any advice is highly regarded

UserWarning: Found unknown categories in columns [4] during transform. These unknown categories will be encoded as all zeros

````
grid_transformer = make_column_transformer((OneHotEncoder(drop='if_binary',
                   handle_unknown='ignore', warn), categorical_feat),
                    (RobustScaler(), num_feat), remainder='passthrough')
grid_preprocessing = make_pipeline(grid_transformer, 
                                   SelectPercentile(mutual_info_regression, 


grid_search = GridSearchCV(model, params_grid, scoring='neg_root_mean_squared_error',
                                         verbose=1, n_jobs=8)

percentile=50))

```
````